# Room Data-base how to implement item that needs columns from 2 entities

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, dao, android-livedata

I've created database with Room with MVVM, and I'm facing a problem I hope you could help me solve this.

I have a database containing 3 entities `Player`, `Group` and `Standings`, where Standings is the relationship between `Player` and `Group`.
The things is that I want to present standings, but `Standings` only contains the IDs of `Group` and `Player`, and I want it to also show the name of the player which is in `Player`, and I'm using `LiveData`, `adapters` and `ViewModels`, so when I return the list of `LiveData<List<Standings>>` to observe, it doesn't contain the name of the player.

**Does someone know how I can pass the name as well?**

The only solution that I could think of is to create new class that has a Standing and the name(String) as the instances and then return it to observe.

But it doesn't feel natural so I thought I could find here a better, more elegant solution.

```
     groupStandingsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new GroupStandingsViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), 0)).get(GroupStandingsViewModel.class);
    groupStandingsViewModel.getAllStandings().observe(this, new Observer<List<Standings>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Standings> standings) {
            adapter.setStanding(standings);
        }
    });
```

I'm expecting to be able to have both the standings and the names as given in the `onChanged` function of the observe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only solution that I could think of is to create new class that
>   has a Standing and the name(String) as the instances and then return
>   it to observe.
>
> But it doesn't feel natural so I thought I could find here a better,
>   more elegant solution.

It may sound unnatural but you will need some new code, so what else? (P.S. that's rhetorical).

I'd suggest a new class is the way to but something like:-

```
public class PlayerGroupStanding {

    @Embedded
    Standings standing;
    String playerName;
    long playerId;
    String groupName;
    long groupId;

    public PlayerGroupStanding() {
    }

    public Standings getStanding() {
        return standing;
    }

    public void setStanding(Standings standing) {
        this.standing = standing;
    }

    public long getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(long playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public long getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupname(String groupname) {
        this.groupName = groupname;
    }
}
```

This could be used in conjunction with a Dao Query along the lines of :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM standings JOIN player ON mapToPlayer = playerId JOIN `group` ON mapToGroup = groupId")
List<PlayerGroupStanding> getAllStandingsWithPlayerAndGroupDetails();
```

- Note the above makes many assumptions as to names, although the given names should be self-explantory.
- Note that the names of the variables e.g. playerName should match the column name as returned from the query.

## Additional

Re comment

> what object does the SELECT returns in a query. I understand that if I use a SELECT * then the object will be of the class that is in the FROM. but when I returns columns, what will be the object that I need to mention in the LiveData>? Where can if find information about it? Thank you very much in advance:D

The SELECT actually returns a Cursor, it's the annotation that then writes the code that extracts the columns as per the definition of the method mapping the columns according to the class's member names to return the object, if additional columns exist they are ignored. The FROM clause doesn't determine the resultant object returned the method after the @Query does according to the type returned from that method.

The actual code can be found after building (Ctrl + F9) in the generated code of the project e.g.

[image]

So for the example above then the respective method that is generated in the Dao's code (i.e. Dao suffixd with _impl) is :-

```
@Override
  public List<PlayerGroupStandings> getAllPlayerGroupStandings() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM standings JOIN player ON mapToPlayer = playerId JOIN `group` ON mapToGroup = groupId";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, true, null);
    try {
      final int _cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "mapToPlayer");
      final int _cursorIndexOfMapToGroup = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "mapToGroup");
      final LongSparseArray<ArrayList<Player>> _collectionPlayers = new LongSparseArray<ArrayList<Player>>();
      final LongSparseArray<ArrayList<Group>> _collectionGroup = new LongSparseArray<ArrayList<Group>>();
      while (_cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (!_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer)) {
          final long _tmpKey = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer);
          ArrayList<Player> _tmpPlayersCollection = _collectionPlayers.get(_tmpKey);
          if (_tmpPlayersCollection == null) {
            _tmpPlayersCollection = new ArrayList<Player>();
            _collectionPlayers.put(_tmpKey, _tmpPlayersCollection);
          }
        }
        if (!_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup)) {
          final long _tmpKey_1 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup);
          ArrayList<Group> _tmpGroupCollection = _collectionGroup.get(_tmpKey_1);
          if (_tmpGroupCollection == null) {
            _tmpGroupCollection = new ArrayList<Group>();
            _collectionGroup.put(_tmpKey_1, _tmpGroupCollection);
          }
        }
      }
      _cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
      __fetchRelationshipplayerAsarmAndroidroommigrationsPlayer(_collectionPlayers);
      __fetchRelationshipgroupAsarmAndroidroommigrationsGroup(_collectionGroup);
      final List<PlayerGroupStandings> _result = new ArrayList<PlayerGroupStandings>(_cursor.getCount());
      while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
        final PlayerGroupStandings _item;
        final Standings _tmpStandings;
        if (! (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer) && _cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup))) {
          _tmpStandings = new Standings();
          final Long _tmpMapToPlayer;
          _tmpMapToPlayer = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer);
          _tmpStandings.setMapToPlayer(_tmpMapToPlayer);
          final Long _tmpMapToGroup;
          _tmpMapToGroup = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup);
          _tmpStandings.setMapToGroup(_tmpMapToGroup);
        }  else  {
          _tmpStandings = null;
        }
        ArrayList<Player> _tmpPlayersCollection_1 = null;
        if (!_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer)) {
          final long _tmpKey_2 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToPlayer);
          _tmpPlayersCollection_1 = _collectionPlayers.get(_tmpKey_2);
        }
        if (_tmpPlayersCollection_1 == null) {
          _tmpPlayersCollection_1 = new ArrayList<Player>();
        }
        ArrayList<Group> _tmpGroupCollection_1 = null;
        if (!_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup)) {
          final long _tmpKey_3 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMapToGroup);
          _tmpGroupCollection_1 = _collectionGroup.get(_tmpKey_3);
        }
        if (_tmpGroupCollection_1 == null) {
          _tmpGroupCollection_1 = new ArrayList<Group>();
        }
        _item = new PlayerGroupStandings();
        _item.standings = _tmpStandings;
        _item.players = _tmpPlayersCollection_1;
        _item.group = _tmpGroupCollection_1;
        _result.add(_item);
      }
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for the answer:)
secondly, I have a follow-up question, what object does the SELECT returns in a query. I understand that if I use a SELECT * then the object will be of the class that is in the FROM. but when I returns columns, what will be the object that I need to mention in the LiveData<List<        >>? Where can if find information about it? Thank you very much in advance:D

Comment: @YohaiM I've updated the answer to explain. If found the answer helpful then please tick it as the answer.

Comment: First thank you, it was very good explanation. Is it possible to "tell" the `Dao` how to map the columns in the object that is returned? So that I can fit to the `PlayerGroupStanding` by myself? Is it supported by Room?

Comment: @YohaiM I'm not sure what you by how, you could use AS to rename extracted columns via the SELECT. e.g. say you had a column called FRED and you wanted it to fit into a variable named Mary then `SELECT FRED as Mary ....` If you mean type then that could be dodgy ground but you could do SELECT CAST(FRED AS REAL) but may get unexpected results.